# Duplicate songs in Noise and Lollypop

Tags: music

I've been having problems adding music files to both Noise and Lollypop libraries. Songs are showing twice, even though Files only show one file.

[image: Lollypop duplicate songs]

I have tried clearing cache and resetting databases with:

`rm -rf ~/.cache/noise/
rm -rf ~/.local/share/noise/
rm -rf ~/.cache/lollypop/
rm -rf ~/.local/share/lollypop/`

but to no effect. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Answered on https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/7jmf2n/duplicate_songs_in_noise_and_lollypop/dskadbd/

I noticed this happening when I import music with the "Import to Library…" menu item in settings. I figure it could be a matter of the "Copy imported folders to Library" preference where the program could be importing a folder and adding it, then see the files copied in the library and show those too.

In fact browsing the sqlite database shows the double entries one with a path in ~/Music and the other at the original path where they were imported from.

I haven't delved much into trying to debug this since I have to rebuild the library every time and it's time-consuming, but since Noise seems to have added the copied files on its own I just disabled "Copy imported folders to Library" and started manually moving files into ~/Music, the changes will be reflected automatically in my Library.

**tl;dr**

disable copying to library and move files by hand to ~/Music
(or wherever your music library is)